# Blender OBJ over 5gb, what is causing this?

Tags: export, obj

I'm still new to Blender but I've been exporting a few projects as objs and it's been fine for size.

I wanted to upgrade my current inn room asset so I added a few things. I even attempted some pbr materials and baked them with simple bake (I couldn't get them to show up in my export to clip studio paint so I gave up on that)

Now I'm trying just to export a simple obj with no materials, no nodes, nothing. (I deleted them all.)

Can someone tell me how to look for what's causing this spike in memory usage and such a large file when I export? (I did un-subdivide just to try and help, it didn't really do anything, I also cleared data blocks)

[image][image]